# Why does my Motorola G4 loose its mobile data connectivity while showing 'Suspended' next to the carrier name?

Tags: mobile-data, mobile-network

Suddenly since yesterday, whenever I activate mobile data on my Moto G 4+, it says *suspended* below the carrier name:

[image]

Hence I don't have access. This happens only most of the time, sometimes it actually works.

Rebooting sometime fixes the issue, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Are you exceeding your data plan? Could be a warning from carrier to let you know that you have hit the limit and service is suspended till you buy a data pack

Comment: @beeshyams I thought so too since that's what happened the day before, but afterwards it was back to usual (probably turn of the month). Now I'm not sure, since the problem occurred only after it started working again. Some other users of the same phone complain about the same issue in this forum
https://www.androidpit.de/forum/737976/moto-g4-plus-problem-mobilfunkdaten-angehalten

Comment: Best to check with carrier - my carrier depending on plan either stops service or chokes speed to 2G. So it is technically connected but at lowest speed

Comment: Yes, I was notified that for the remainder of the period, my speed would be decreased (and I felt it too), but no indication that I would be cut off completely. Also it works sporadically, so that explanation doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: That's something that won't be entertained here being *Android independent*...sorry

Comment: I have the exact same problem as far as I can tell: Mobile data stops working, it shows an exclamation mark and 'Suspended' and only power cycling my Moto G4 restores the data connectivity. I found a very similar error report at https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Moto-G4-Moto-G4-Plus-Moto-G4/Mobile-data-connection-problem-in-moto-g4-plus/td-p/3558482. But unfortunately no solution. I don't think that it's an carrier issue, but an specific issue of the G4.

Comment: @Flow My Moto G has different Bugs all the time, so I think that's very likely.